# `Get-ChildItem` does not throw a `cannot find path` error in a class function of PowerShell as expected

Tags: windows, powershell, cicd, wsl-2, powershell-7.3

I'm working on a dev tool based on PowerShell. But it always failed in Ubuntu-Latest CI/CD tests. If interested, please check the [GitHub Link of Actions](https://github.com/Zhaopudark/PSComputerManagementZp/actions)

After a day of trying, I found and minimized the process of reproducing the problem.

- Platform: Both Windows and WSL2 show the same problem
- PSVersion: 7.3.6

Consider a directory `${Home}/test/` with a `file test_in_method.ps1` and a file `test_out_of_method.ps1` as:

```
${Home}/test/
|----test_in_method.ps1
|----test_out_of_method.ps1
|----(no other items, i.e., no other dirs or files)
```

The `test_in_method.ps1` is as:

```
# PowerShell 7.3.6 on Windows Or Linux
# test_in_method.ps1
class FormattedFileSystemPath {
    FormattedFileSystemPath([string] $Path) {
        $link_target  = $this.PreProcess()
    }
    [string] PreProcess(){
        Write-Verbose "PWD is:$PWD" -Verbose
        return (Get-ChildItem 'usr'| Where-Object Name -eq 'sbin')
    }
}
Write-Verbose ([FormattedFileSystemPath]::new('???')) -Verbose
```

, and the `test_out_of_method.ps1` is as:

```
# PowerShell 7.3.6 on Windows Or Linux
# test_out_of_method.ps1
class FormattedFileSystemPath {

    FormattedFileSystemPath([string] $Path) {
        Write-Verbose "PWD is:$PWD" -Verbose
        $link_target = (Get-ChildItem 'usr'| Where-Object Name -eq 'sbin')
    }
}
Write-Verbose ([FormattedFileSystemPath]::new('???')) -Verbose
```

First, test `test_in_method.ps1`  as:

```
pwsh
cd "${Home}/test/"
./ test_in_method.ps1
```

The output is:

```
VERBOSE: PWD is:C:\Users\User\test
VERBOSE: FormattedFileSystemPath
```

Second, test `test_out_of_method.ps1`  as:

```
pwsh
cd "${Home}/test/"
./ test_out_of_method.ps1
```

The out put is:

```
VERBOSE: PWD is:C:\Users\User\test
Get-ChildItem: C:\Users\User\test\test_out_of_method.ps1:7
Line |
   7 |          $link_target = (Get-ChildItem 'usr'| Where-Object Name -eq 's …
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find path 'C:\Users\User\test\usr' because it does not exist.
VERBOSE: FormattedFileSystemPath
```

**Expected behavior**: both `test_in_method.ps1` and `test_out_of_method.ps1` throw `cannot find path` errors

**Actual behavior**: only `test_out_of_method.ps1` throws `cannot find path` errors but `test_in_method.ps1` does not.

I have tested on my local machines, and both Windows 11 (PowerShellv7.3.6) and WSL2(PowerShellv7.3.5) show the above phenomenon.

Even more strangely, when put into a CI/CD environment, see [here](https://github.com/Zhaopudark/PSComputerManagementZp/actions/runs/5999463982), either of the above writes (whether put Get-ChildItem into a class function or a constructor function) can both throw errors as expected.

What's the problem? Why? And how can I deal with it?  Why `Get-ChildItem` does not throw a `cannot find path` error in the class method as expected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does path exist?  Code may be using temp space when you do not set the path.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, The path is nonexistent. I have modified the question to be more precise. Actually, it should thrown errors but when I moved the codes into a class function, the errors did not show. But my project relies on these throw errors.

Comment: An exception can only be caught once unless the method that captures the exception uses a THROW.  Many library method do not use THROW so the application cannot process the exception.  Powershell has lots of different outputs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Interesting. It seems to only suppress errors from methods with explicit return parameters, if you change the method signature to `[void]PreProcess()` then the error appears again

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. The deadliest thing is that the phenomenon happens in my local machines, but not in the GitHub Actions environment( where errors are thrown always). So I didn't even realize the problem.

Comment: if you want it to throw then you should be using `-EA Stop` on all the cmdlets calls. Or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has 2 aspects and can be answered respectively:

- Why `Get-ChildItem` does not throw a `cannot find path` error in a class method as expected? Because:

  1. There are 2 types of errors, i.e.,  `terminating errors` and `non-terminating errors`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/error-reporting-concepts?view=powershell-7.3).
  2. The `cannot find path` is a `non-terminating error` but `non-terminating errors` are not surfaced by class methods, see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20175) and [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9702).
- Why the phenomenon is different the local machines and CI/CD environments?

  1. [`$ErrorActionPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#erroractionpreference) can determine how PowerShell responds to a non-terminating error, an error that doesn't stop the cmdlet processing.
  2. Git-Hub CI/CD environments usually have `$ErrorActionPreference= 'stop'` that is set by many configuration scripts, see [an action example](https://github.com/Zhaopudark/PSComputerManagementZp/actions/runs/6008046824/job/16295119855), while local machines usually have `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'`, which is the default state that displays the error message and continues executing.

And how to do it?

I think the best way is as @Santiago Squarzon's comments, adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-ChildItem` in class methods. Because it follows the principle of Occam's Razor, with the minimized scope of changes.

Thanks for every above comments and advice.